# Issue with removing symbols from a string

Tags: c#

I'd like to remove every `"\n"` symbol from every single array element. But after using this code nothing happens;

```
string[] Words = TextBox.Text.Split(' ');

for (int i = 0; i < Words.Length; i++)
{
    Words[i].Replace("\n", "");
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Why are you `Spliting` the text here ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Words[i] = Words[i].Replace("\n", "");`

Answer (score 4):

`String.Replace` returns a new string; it doesn't affect the original. You need to use

```
Words[i] = Words[i].Replace("\n", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable.  That means that any operation on a string that has already had it's value set, returns a new string and does not change the original string.

As others have said, you need to assign the result of your replace operation to a new string.